# exit(int) gives wrong value

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, return

I have a multi-process program that runs 4 processes that should return exit value.
But when process reaches exit(int) line it actually returns other value to wait()
For example:
exit(1) will give value of 256 to wait()
exit(3) - 768
exit(4) - 1024
and so on. I guess it returns a value in exit(int) multiplied by 256.
Why this happens and how to fix(?) this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `exit()`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i'm using ubuntu.
I need exit to terminate process and recieve termination code

Comment: You can only **portably** call `exit()` with one of the values `EXIT_FAILURE`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot directly consume the value provided by `wait` as it encodes additional information in an implementation-defined manner. You must use the `WEXITSTATUS` macro if the process exited and/or other macros like `WTERMSIG` or `WSTOPSIG` if a signal was involved. Adapted from `man 2 wait`:

```
int wstatus;
w = wait(&wstatus);
if (w < 0) {
    perror("wait");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (WIFEXITED(wstatus)) {
    printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(wstatus));
} else if (WIFSIGNALED(wstatus)) {
    printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(wstatus));
} else if (WIFSTOPPED(wstatus)) {
    printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(wstatus));
} else if (WIFCONTINUED(wstatus)) {
    printf("continued\n");
}
```

On my system (Ubuntu through WSL), WEXITSTATUS is defined as:

```cpp
#define __WEXITSTATUS(status)   (((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)
...
# define WEXITSTATUS(status)    __WEXITSTATUS (status)
```

This matches up with what you observe, where the obtained value is 256 times the expected exit code. However, because the encoding is defined by the implementation, you should not make this assumption yourself.